# How to set Java path using batch file

Tags: java, batch-file

So I am new to using and creating batch files. I was wondering what is wrong with my file. I want to make it where it sets the path so I can compile my java file in cmd. Here is my code

```
@echo off
:start

rem set path="c:\Program Files\java\jdk.1.8.0_102";
set path=%path%;c:\Program Files\java\jdk.1.8.0_102
cls
pause
rem goto start
```

I am not to sure which one is right between the 2 paths so I was just testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"

setx PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin";

JAVA_HOME: stores location of the JDK’s installation directory.
PATH: stores paths of directories where the operating system will look, to launch the requested programs quickly.

Comment: so it should be setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin" than also setx why is the x there? I am a little confused

Comment: setx wil change the master environment, set itself changes only the volatile current sessions environment vars.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.1.8.0_102\bin";%path%
```